# Can you run an unmodified EAR in JBOSS EAP 7 and Wildfly 10

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-10

I'm trying to find a conclusive answer to this question and I'm not having any luck.  Can an application compiled into an EAR (1 binary) be loaded into JBOSS EAP 7 and also, without modification be loaded into a Wildfly 10 server?

Or can the business code remain unmodified but require different JARs to be pulled into the EAR to make it load?

Comment: Are you asking if you can deploy the same binary to JBoss EAP 7 and WildFly 10?

Comment: Yes, or if not whether the change is simply to reference a set of JBOSS JARs instead of a set of wildfly JARs

Comment: There really shouldn't be any changes required. They're both Java EE 7 containers. I'm not sure what you mean by "JBoss JARs". Generally speaking JAR's provided by the container shouldn't be added to an EAR.

Comment: Generally speaking... My experience with the earlier wildfly containers left something to be desired.  Regardless my question is that can I deploy unmodified an EAR to JBOSS EAP 7 and Wildfly 10

Comment: Yes, you can deploy the same EAR to JBoss EAP 7 and WildFly 10.